# Build artefacts are missing, you must build project first - At deploy in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I created a project in NetBeans with Maven aiming to deploy in google app engine. When I try to make the deploy displays the following error message:

```
Build artefacts are missing, you must first build project.
```

Would have a way to fix this?

[This link has something about this error](https://kenai.com/jira/browse/NBAPPENGINE-38?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aworklog-tabpanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this tutorial is available on Google Developers to deploy from the command line. Thus solving my problem.

[Uploading Your Application](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading)